# Change the colour of text that overlaps an image

Tags: html, css, flexbox, crop

The look I'm trying to achieve is if you have black text on a white page, but that text runs into an image. The section of text that is over the image changes it's colour.

I have a 'working' (not flexible) example here using a `data` attribute to grab the same text and set it on the `:before` element using `content`:

https://codepen.io/moy/pen/rNeaGbJ

```css
/* General Shit */

body {
  color: #000;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 3.6rem;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.btn {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding: 15px 60px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}


/* Grid */

.grid {
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 30px 0;
  max-width: 1000px;
}

.grid__item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
}

.grid--flip .grid__item {
  float: right;
}

.grid__item--caption {
  padding: 30px 60px;
}

.one-half {
  width: 50%;
}


/* Title */

.title-wrap {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin-left: -60%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.grid--flip .title-wrap {
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: -60%;
}

.title {
  color: #000;
}

.grid--flip .title {
  color: #fff;
}

.title:before {
  color: #fff;
  content: attr(data-title);
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 27.75%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.grid--flip .title:before {
  color: #000;
  width: 34.75%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__item grid__item--image one-half">
    <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/800/800" />
  </div>
  <div class="grid__item grid__item--caption one-half">
    <div class="title-wrap">
      <h2 class="title" data-title="Title goes here">Title goes here</h2>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn">Shop Collection</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="grid grid--flip">
  <div class="grid__item grid__item--image one-half">
    <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/800/800" />
  </div>
  <div class="grid__item grid__item--caption one-half">
    <div class="title-wrap">
      <h2 class="title" data-title="Title goes here">Title goes here</h2>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn">Shop Collection</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem with this is if...

1. I adjust the width of the container, all the values are off and it looks broken.
2. the title is longer and wraps onto multiple lines, it is cut off due to the overflow
3. And why the widths are what they are on the `:before` element (if someone could explain that'd be great ha)

So I tried a version using `px` values instead of `%` which fixes the issues of changing the container width. However I still have the issue of it not behaving right when text wraps onto 2 lines.

Example (using px): https://codepen.io/moy/pen/JjXoMvb

Can anyone think of a better solution for this? Am I overcomplicating this or missing something obvious?

**Edit: PX example wrong incorrect, updated link now.**

Comment: If you need to have a certain set of characters on that image, I would go with editing images or separating the element. Otherwise, going by your method the browser will break the next section until you reduce the font-size.

Comment: Yeah it's more just a quirky little effect I'm trying. Rather than a safety feature to make sure text is legible. So not too concerns about how many characters go over the image. Just want the text to overlap an image and for the colour to change when it does. Which I guess I have working ...just not when the text wraps! Might just need to  make sure they're short words or have predefined line-breaks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [CSS clip-path property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)

Example

```css
:root {
  --size: 100px;
}

.resizable {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: calc(var(--size) * 3);
  height: calc(var(--size) * 2);
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.divider {
  height: 100px;
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
}

.left {
  color: blue;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, var(--size) 0, var(--size) var(--size), 0 var(--size));
}

.right {
  color: red;
  clip-path: polygon(var(--size) 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 var(--size), var(--size) var(--size));
}

.container-reverse img {
  float: right;
}

.container-reverse .left {
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% var(--size), calc(100% - var(--size)) var(--size), calc(100% - var(--size)) 0);
}

.container-reverse .right {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - var(--size)) 0, calc(100% - var(--size)) var(--size), 100% var(--size), 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.container-reverse h1 {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="resizable">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="title left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</h1>
    <h1 class="title right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</h1>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
  </div>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="container container-reverse">
    <h1 class="title left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</h1>
    <h1 class="title right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</h1>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks really interesting, I think I Just need the 2 colours - it's for a creative piece so more for visual effect. Do you think if it just had the 2 it could be achieved with the :before/after classes? I've got that here: https://codepen.io/moy/pen/JjXopPy but not sure you can use clip with that?

Comment: The 3 different colors were just for demonstration purposes, you could just change the green to red also. However, after I posted, I read that you should use `clip-path` instead. I changed the snippet to using that instead, which actually makes it simpler and only required 2 elements.

Comment: I tried using `::before`, but the issue is that if you clip the main element, the `::before` element is positioned outside the clipped region and is therefore not rendered. You could only clip the `::before` element, but then you get this ugly overlay where you can see there is red text below the blue.

Comment: I tried here and I think it's pretty close: https://codepen.io/moy/pen/poyvarb

Probably seems to be on the blocks with images on the right. It would be good if the mast was just over the image rather than the text outside the image - but I dunno if you can change the position/direction of the 'clip'?

Comment: For reversing simplest is to just override the path with a new one, I edited my example.

Comment: Thanks! I think all my `flex` stuff was interfering. I think this is looking pretty good now: https://codepen.io/moy/pen/dyMPmmP I thought I'd swap out my px values for %. I haven't used `clip` much but any idea why 180px would display differently using `clip` and `clip-path: inset`?

Comment: It has to do with how `clip: rect()` and `clip-path: inset()` takes arguments. Inset takes `top right bottom left` while `clip: rect` only takes arguments relative to the left and top. Just always use `clip-path`, it's better. Explained better in these links: [clip rect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape) [inset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/basic-shape)

Comment: Thanks! God it's been a while since i've done some dev work (all design now) but was interesting to look into this (and I've never used clip). I think this all works now https://codepen.io/moy/pen/dyMPmmP - I might do another version where it uses margin-left/right rather than left/right so the text area but I've had enough of math/percentages for one day haha - thanks again!